# Need to show if to_char(date_column,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2015 -05-03' then 'y' else 'n'

Tags: postgresql

I need to do an expression in my date field as below, is it the correct format:

```sql
if to_char(date_column,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2015 -05-03' then 'y' else 'n'
```

Thanks
Aj

Comment: The `to_char()` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `case`:

```
select (case when to_char(date_column,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2015-05-03'
             then 'y' else 'n'
        end)
```

You probably don't need the `to_char()`:

```
select (case when date_column > '2015-05-03'
             then 'y' else 'n'
        end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the documentation on `IF ... ELSE ...` statement in Postgresql ([docs here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)). So your could would look something like this:

```
IF to_char(date_column,'yyyy-mm-dd') > '2015 -05-03'
THEN 
    RETURN 'y';
ELSE
    RETURN 'n';
END IF;
```